# How to install extensions online in VS 2019 for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

VS 2019 does not have an option to install extensions online? How do I install my .vsix file manually? I'm aware of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017617/how-to-install-vs-code-extension-manually) to install .vsix manually but VS 2019 does not have this option.

[image]

Install from file... does not handle .vsix file either when I tried installing it from file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is in general not possible... see here:
[Installing extensions on Visual Studio 2017 mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825177/installing-extensions-on-visual-studio-2017-mac)

(I found this thread because I wanted to do something similar!)