# How to install VS code for web extension manually?

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins

so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017617/how-to-install-vs-code-extension-manually) is for vs code for desktop.
is there any way to install visx file directly for the web version? thankyou

Comment: Just to double-check, by "web version", do you mean [this one](https://vscode.dev/)?

Comment: @cocomac oh yeah it is