# VSCode issue when trying to install the Python extension: "end of central directory record signature not found"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When trying to install the Python extension I get the following error:

`Error while installing 'Python' extension. Please check the [log](command:workbench.action.showWindowLog) for more details.`

The log says this...

`[error] end of central directory record signature not found,end of central directory record signature not found: Error: end of central directory record signature not found,end of central directory record signature not found`

I have tried to install manually and get the error in the image.

Not sure what to try next

Comment: Have you tried googling the error? I found these that might be useful: VSCode issue [34730](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34730), VSCode Python issues [17491](//github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17491) and [17062](//github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17062); SO: [can't install python extension in vscode](//stackoverflow.com/q/73492693), [Error "end of central directory record signature not found" while installing ionide-fsharp in vscode](//stackoverflow.com/q/41530269). Although, when you say "install manually", you mean from VSIX? Some of these links do talk about that.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: possible workaround: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34730#issuecomment-333437277. possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131232

Comment: What version of vscode are you using? Have you tried using the latest version

Comment: Yes, I have tried to install from VSIX and get the error Command 'Extensions: Install form VSIX' resulted in an error end of central directory record signature not found. I am using v1.77.3 and have tried most all of those links with no luck.

Comment: I was finally able to resolve it using the CLI method mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017617/how-to-install-vs-code-extension-manually/50232194#50232194

Answer (score 1):

After looking at most of the posts on internet around it I found out the solution:

```html
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin> .\code --install-extension "C:\Pathto\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.23.13521007.vsix"
```

[Microsoft Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace?fireglass_rsn=true#:%7E:text=Install%20from%20a%20VSIX,-You%20can%20manually&text=Using%20the%20Install%20from%20VSIX,path%20to%20the%20.vsix%20file.&fireglass_params&tabid=a3f01ef75481a239&application_server_address=euroclear5.prod.fire.glass&popup=true&is_right_side_popup=false&start_with_session_counter=1)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and discovered that this error was caused by version incompatibility.

Download directly from this link and install manually.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-python/vsextensions/python/2023.14.0/vspackage

If it doesn't work, it's because this isn't the right version, so try other versions.